# macro definition not passed to a header file in a dll

Tags: c, visual-studio, logging, dll, macros

I have a dll (let us say named `test.dll`) and this dll includes a header file called `logger.h`
(This is a logging file written by Andriy Tylychko)

in logger.h header file there is this macro:

```
#if !defined(LOGGING_DISABLED)
//statement A
#else
//statement B
#endif
```

In the dllmain.cpp
I have

```
#ifndef LOGGING_DISABLED
#define LOGGING_DISABLED
#endif
```

When I load this dll, and I attach and debug, I found out that statement A is being executed not statement B! Isn't the macro definition LOGGING_DISABLED should be passed to the logger.h?

Edit:
I do also use the preprocessor definition in visual studio 2008 in the dll to define the macro `LOGGING_DISABLED`

Comment: You do define `LOGGING_DISABLED` when you compile the DLL, right?

Comment: @Biffen yes, I do in the preprocessor definition

Comment: And you `#define` it before you `#include` the header file?

Comment: @Biffen, not sure I will double check, but isnt it enough to define it in the visual studio preprocessor definition?

Comment: Yeah, that should be enough. To debug it you could put an `#error` after the `#if` and one after the `#else`. Oh, and make sure you've spelled the variable right everywhere.